# Rails invalid id passed in nested_attributes causes 'undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm implementing a Rails app that features the models:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorisations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorisations
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :documents, through: :categorisations
end

class Categorisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :category

  validates_presence_of :document
  validates_presence_of :category

  validates_uniqueness_of :category, scope: :document
end
```

The presence of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Document` allows attaching categories to a document at document-creation-time. This generally works fine, except for the case when an invalid category-id (one for which no category exists) is passed in through nested attributes. In this case:

```
document = Document.new({
  # .. attributes ..,
  categorisations_attributes: {
    '0' => {
      # .. more attributes ..,
      category_id: some_invalid_id
    }
  }
})

# Ouch, this results in 'NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass'
document.valid?
```

Unsurprisingly, I get the same error when attempting to `document.save`. At this point, it looks like I could detect and preempt this by checking for something like `document.categorisations.first.category.nil?`. This seems to me less than ideal however, as it is not in line with usual Rails validation practice and I cannot follow the common pattern of detecting invalidity on `document.save` (through a `false` return value).

Am I missing some Rails best practice / better way of laying out my models that would mitigate this?

[**Edit**: Here's a stack trace for the case of `document.valid?`]

```
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:56:in `build_relation'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:22:in `validate_each'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb:153:in `block in validate'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_before_29'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__1039810079386051889__validate__callbacks'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:373:in `run_validations!'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1039810079386051889__validation__callbacks'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_validations!'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:314:in `valid?'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:70:in `valid?'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:304:in `association_valid?'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:293:in `block in validate_collection_association'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:293:in `each'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:293:in `validate_collection_association'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:207:in `block in add_autosave_association_callbacks'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:153:in `instance_eval'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:153:in `block in define_non_cyclic_method'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:397:in `_run__779968926416857275__validate__callbacks'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:373:in `run_validations!'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__779968926416857275__validation__callbacks'
activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_validations!'
activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/validations.rb:314:in `valid?'
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:70:in `valid?'
```

[**Edit 2**:]

I updated the question to include the `validates_uniqueness_of :category, scope: :document` constraint in the `Categorisation` model. *Removing that eliminates the Nil error* resulting in the much saner, validation error 'Categorisations category can't be blank' instead. However, the problem persists when the validation is in place.

Comment: This looks like an actual bug in ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how validations work, if you try to use `association` instead of just `association_id`, but you can try to use `validates_each` instead of `validates_presence_of` for validation in `Categorisation` model:

```
validates_each :category_id do |record, attr, value|
  unless Category.exists?(id: value)
    record.errors.add(attr, "does not exist")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I'm getting the same behaviour as before. (Furthermore, as far as I can tell, this would be a problem when leveraging nested attributes to _create_ categories)

Comment: Can you add all your stack trace? Maybe we can find something there.

Comment: Sure, see edited question. I added a stack trace for the case of `document.valid?`.

Comment: Is there any other validations in `Categorisation` model? For some reason it tries to run `Uniqueness` validation.

Comment: That's a good point and, yes, the `Categorisation` model contains `validates_uniqueness_of :category, scope: :document`. I updated the original question reflect that. Also, it turns out that _removing that constraint eliminates the Nil error_. I now get a validation error 'Categorisations category can't be blank' which is obviously much closer to what I'd expect. In an attempt to simplify the question I left out important details it seems. My bad. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: I think you should use `validates_uniqueness_of :category_id, scope: document_id` and let checking of category existence on `validates_each` above in the answer and it should work in the way you want.